# Unit test MOQ Service call to DB

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq

I've done a lot of looking around and I see that there are a lot of example of mocking a service, as well as mocking a Databse using a repository. But how would I MOQ a service that calls a store procedure? Well I have to do it desperately? One to the the service and one to test the DataBase? Cause if that is the case then I am not sure how to test the service, since all my service does is call the store procedure and return the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot stub/mock stored procedure at its simple form. However you can stub them by introducing some sort of an abstraction around it. If your service only call the stored procedure you don't need to test the service. If your service does other things, then you want abstract away you store procedure call to a repository or something similar and stub that instead then test your service.

Comment: Will all it does is call the Store procedure, but in the process it also make sure I have the permisson to to do the call, get the session etc. Those wouldn't need to be call correct? Anyways your response has put me at ease thnx.

Comment: Yes you are right. If the service only does a stored procedure call but uses some cross cutting concerns/infrastructure like permission you don't need to test those with the unit test. You would typically test these using acceptance tests or integration tests.